# How can I insert data from this loop in sqlite

Tags: python, syntax-error, operationalerror

I am trying to insert data from a loop that is similar to this.

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for word in words:
     c.execute("insert into Words (word), values (?)",(word))
     print(word) 
     conn.commit

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Expected result is similar to this:

[image]

I am getting an error. But I am not sure how to correctly format this code right.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.execute("insert into Words (word), values (?)",(word))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong list : 
commit() not commit because it is a method
"insert into Words (word) values (?)",(word,) not "insert into Words (word), values (?)",(word)

right code is:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for word in words:
    c.execute("insert into Words (word) values (?)",(word,))
    print(word) 
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Don't worry, happy codding

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting an error because you can't place a single item in parenthesis to make it a tuple - so `(word)` isn't the way to go. It should be one of these (whichever one is more readable to you):

```
c.execute("insert into Words (word) values (?)",(word,))
```

Notice the comma inserted after `word` to make it a tuple. Or:

```
c.execute("insert into Words (word) values (?)",[word])
```

Which would make `word` the only element in a `list`

You can see for yourself in the console that doing something like `('hello')` isn't equal to `('hello',)`. The first one remains a string, the second one is a tuple (which is what's needed in your command).

Edit: Also, you had a comma in that command that shouldn't be there

Comment: Still getting same error on both c.execute("insert into Words (word), values (?)",(word,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: @ned sorry i edited that, that comma isn't needed, try again with the updated code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use f-string:

`c.execute(f"INSERT INTO Words (word), values ({word})")`

This is much easier to read :) but requires python 3.6+

```py
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()

    words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    for word in words:
         c.execute(f"INSERT INTO Words (word), values ({word})")
         print(word) 
         conn.commit()
```

Comment: this will work, but in my experience it's a really bad idea to use f-stings on sqlite commands (not to mention is will be really difficult for large numbers of values)

Comment: Not in what I have tried as it leaves SQL code looking SQL. All the ? ? ? are easy to mix up.